# Bootstrap 5 fixed nav scrolls a bit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I update a template from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5
With bootstrap 4 i didin't notice this fact.
A the beginning i thought that the problem was coming from the fact that they added a flex container inside the navbar but doesn't seems to be the problem
I have a fixed navbar that on mobile scrolls down just a bit even thought it has `postion:fixed`
How is that even possible ?

You can see it live [here](https://www.cristiangiro.com/all_projects/myne%20app/index.html)

```
      <nav
        class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top"
        style="background-color: #ffffff"
      >
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img
              id="logosvg"
              src="assets/img/mine.svg"
              height="40px"
              alt="Myne social logo"
              style="margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left: 0.5em"
          /></a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"
              ></span>
          </button>
          <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
            id="navbarNav"
          >
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#aboutus"
                  >About us</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#mynepulse">Myne Pulse</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#instantgratification"
                  >Instant Gratification</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#partners">Our Parterns</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item desktop">
                <a
                  href=""
                  target="_blank"
                  ><button type="button" class="blue">Get Started</button></a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Update :
As you can see from the screenshot when , on mobile view , you scroll down the top bar goes a bit up, and then goes back on is position if you scoll up.

[image]

Comment: The page couldn't be found

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 sorry , old link . I updated , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your CSS code then everything should work as you want.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .fixed-top {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1030;
        height: 80px;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry , doesn't work . And aniway that rule is alredy on the css , is coming directly from bootstrap

Comment: You mean when you scroll down the navigation becomes a bit smaller or? This code should work for the desktop version.

Comment: the problem is on the mobile version. i'll try to make a screenshot to made myself more clear

Comment: I think if you add a container class to your main section: `<main class="container">` then everything will work together. — One other note — your nav section is 76px height (normally), but you’re setting the margin-top on the row below your navbar to 5rem. If you set it to 4.75rem, it would eliminate the 4px gap between the bottom of the navbar and the top of the red section.